# Append img from AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm trying `append` `<img>` to a `div` using Ajax (because I need to fetch the name of image from database).

I already get the `<img>` tag on my `div`, also get the `src` attribute to the correct image. But I'm still not seeing the image. I'm just seeing a `<img>` tag with 0 x 0 size. Try to enlarge the size, still see nothing..

I try to open image via link that generated inside `src` attribute, and I can see the image that I want to append..
Why this is happen ?

This is my code

Trigger to function that contain ajax

```
<div class="HotelListDescriptionContent" onclick='showDetailRoom("<?php echo $arrayroomssearch[$arrk]['room_code']?>")'>
```

Function With Ajax

```
function showDetailRoom(roomid)
{
    if(j("#detailroom"+roomid).is(":visible"))
        j("#detailroom"+roomid).hide();
    else
    {
        j.post("inc/querys/roomdetail.php",
        { 
            roomid : roomid,
        },
        function(data){
            // console.log(data);
            j("#detailroom"+roomid).html("");
            // j("#detailroom"+roomid).append($("<option></option>").append("Select your state..."));
            if(data == "empty")
            {
                j("#detailroom"+roomid).append($("<option></option>").append("State Not Found..."));
            }
            else
            {
                j(data.photo).each(function(i,item){
                    // console.log(item);
                    j("#detailroom"+roomid).html("<img scr='<?php echo SITE_URL;?>upload_photos/images/"+item+"'/>");
                })
            }
            j("#detailroom"+roomid).show();
        },
        "json");
    }
}
```

Div target

```
<div id="detailroom<?php echo $arrayroomssearch[$arrk]['room_code'];?>" style="display:none;">
```

Div target (via Inspect Element)

```
<div id="detailroom20" style=""><img scr="http://localhost/bookingbeol/bk-admin/upload_photos/images/kamar3-1476346812.jpg"></div>
```

Div target not showing the image
[image]

Comment: Does the network panel in the chrome dev tools show an attempt to fetch the image?  Do you get any console errors?

Comment: @anied In network panel, there's no attempt to fetch the image. No error in console..

Comment: By the way, kudos on a well formed question-- the problem was clearly explained, and plenty of helpful context was provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it-- you just mistyped it -- should be `src` not `scr`. Easy mistake to make-- difficult to see or notice when scanning or glancing over the code.

Comment: Damn, Thank you for checking my code.. I;m still laughing to my self because have mistyped and asking to this forum lol. Anyway, thanks for helping me find the mistyped code :D

Comment: No problem-- thanks again for such a nicely formed question-- it should be shown to all new users.  And no sweat-- most developers occasionally burn up a bunch of time on a simple mistype-- glad to help!